# ngFileSelect with 2 images upload in a form

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using the angular-file-upload.js .I would like to upload the 2 images in a form, 2 different file uploads and one form submit button.
In my controller:

```
 var uploader = $scope.uploader = $fileUploader.create({
                scope: $scope,
                url:'upload.php',
                autoUpload : true
            });
uploader.addToQueue([uploader.queue[0].file]);
                    uploader.queue[0].upload();
```

amd my html is:

```
<input type="file" ng-file-select class="form-control" 
ng-model="file_course_thumb_image" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
<input type="file" ng-file-select class="form-control" 
ng-model="file_course_thumb_image2" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
```

when trying to upload only second file is uploaded ,but not both first and second files.
Any suggestions ..

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by changes in the `angular-file-upload.js` @author  Danial @version 1.2.8 .In addToQueue function add the condition to empty the queue .

```
if(this.queue.length == 0) {
      this.queue = []      }
```

which can enable us to uploads multiple images at the time of form submit.